# tab effect (CSS)

Tags: html, css, tabs, height

I have written some codes in HTML and CSS. The output is shown in the screenshot. In "TABS" There is a size limit, while the size of the sections within each tab can vary. (In the following codes the height of TABS is 200 pixels)

How to fix this problem? (Please do not suggest any Java Script code.)

The correct form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GACdg.jpg)

If I set it to auto, it will be shown in Fig. 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7MU3.jpg)

```css
.items {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}

.tab-frame input {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}

.tab-frame label {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

    .tab-frame label img {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
    }

    .tab-frame label span:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
        color: white;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .tab-frame label:hover span:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }

    .tab-frame label:hover {
        height: 100px;
    }

#tab1 + label {
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.tab-frame input:checked + label {
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
    height: 110px;
}

    .tab-frame input:checked + label span:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 1;
    }

.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.tab {
    /*display: none;*/
    clear: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}


.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(1) ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(1),
.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(2) ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(1),
.tab-frame input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0%;
}

#tab1 + label {
    background: #479cd7;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%, #2c7eb8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#479cd7), color-stop(100%,#2c7eb8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%,#2c7eb8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%,#2c7eb8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%,#2c7eb8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #479cd7 0%,#2c7eb8 100%);
}

#tab2 + label {
    background: #a9d747;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%, #88b82c 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a9d747), color-stop(100%,#88b82c));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%,#88b82c 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%,#88b82c 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%,#88b82c 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a9d747 0%,#88b82c 100%);
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.header1 {
    background-color: #2c7eb8;
}

.header2 {
    background-color: #88b82c;
}

.header h2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
    <div class="items">
        <div class="tab-frame">
            <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" checked>
            <label for="tab1">
                <span>
                    <img src="../images/home.png" />
                </span>
                <span>صفحه اصلی</span>
            </label>

            <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2">
            <label for="tab2">
                <span>
                    <img src="../images/download.png" />
                </span>
                <span>دانلود رایگان</span>
            </label>



            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab">
                    <div class="header header1">
                        <h2>
                            Home
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab">
                    <div class="header header2">
                        <h2>
                            Free Download
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: وضّح شنو سؤالك بالضبط وماهو الناتج الذي تتوقعه؟

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't clearly know what problem you have?
you want div flexible with your content or you want fixed your div height???

Comment: @AbdullahAlemadi Each tab has contents. The height of this content also varies. (For example, the first tab content is 200 x 500 pixels and a second tab content. Their exact amount is not clear and depends on the texts inside them). In the written code, the height of the tabs is 200 pixels and the final correct shape that we are looking for (Figure 1) appears, but the problem is that its height is constant. While we need some uncertainty

Comment: @Anami flexible

Answer (score 0):

If flexible, you have to move your `background eg. header1, header2` to `.tab div`.
Is this is want you want?

```css
.items {
         width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         float: right;
     }
     
     .tab-frame input {
         display: none;
         width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         float: right;
     }
     
     .tab-frame label {
         display: block;
         float: right;
         cursor: pointer;
         text-align: center;
         width: 110px;
         height: 80px;
         margin: 0 5px;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
         -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s;
         transition: all 0.5s;
     }
     
     .tab-frame label img {
         display: block;
         margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
     }
     
     .tab-frame label span:nth-child(2) {
         opacity: 0;
         color: white;
         -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
         -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s;
         transition: all 0.5s;
     }
     
     .tab-frame label:hover span:nth-child(2) {
         opacity: 1;
         display: block;
     }
     
     .tab-frame label:hover {
         height: 100px;
     }
     
     #tab1 + label {
         margin-right: 35px;
     }
     
     .tab-frame input:checked + label {
         color: white;
         cursor: default;
         height: 110px;
     }
     
     .tab-frame input:checked + label span:nth-child(2) {
         opacity: 1;
     }
     
     .tabs {
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 200px; /* you have to custom set height for your tab wrapper height */
         float: right;
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         overflow: hidden;
         position: relative;
     }
     
     .tab {
         /*display: none;*/
         clear: left;
         overflow: hidden;
         float: right;
         width: 100%;
         max-height: 100%; /* set 100% to  conform the content height */
         position: relative;
     }
     
     .tab-frame input:nth-of-type(1) ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(1),
     .tab-frame input:nth-of-type(2) ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(2) {
         position: absolute;
         top: -100%;
         transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
         -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease;
         -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     }
     
     .tab-frame input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(1),
     .tab-frame input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .tabs .tab:nth-child(2) {
         top: 0%;
     }
     
     #tab1 + label {
         background: #479cd7;
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%, #2c7eb8 100%);
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #479cd7), color-stop(100%, #2c7eb8));
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%, #2c7eb8 100%);
         background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%, #2c7eb8 100%);
         background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #479cd7 0%, #2c7eb8 100%);
         background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #479cd7 0%, #2c7eb8 100%);
     }
     
     #tab2 + label {
         background: #a9d747;
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%, #88b82c 100%);
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #a9d747), color-stop(100%, #88b82c));
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%, #88b82c 100%);
         background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%, #88b82c 100%);
         background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a9d747 0%, #88b82c 100%);
         background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a9d747 0%, #88b82c 100%);
     }
     
     .header {
         width: 100%;
         height: 45px;
         float: right;
         margin-bottom: 40px;
     }
     
     .tab1_background {
         background-color: #2c7eb8;
     }
     
     .tab2_background {
         background-color: #88b82c;
     }
     
     .header h2 {
         float: left;
         margin: 0;
         line-height: 45px;
         padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
         color: white;
         font-weight: bold;
         font-size: 18px;
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
     }
```

```html
<div class="items">
        <div class="tab-frame">
            <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" checked>
            <label for="tab1">
                <span>
                    <img src="../images/home.png" />
                </span>
                <span>صفحه اصلی</span>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2">
            <label for="tab2">
                <span>
                    <img src="../images/download.png" />
                </span>
                <span>دانلود رایگان</span>
            </label>
            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab tab1_background">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>
                            Home
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab tab2_background">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>
                            Free Download
                        </h2>
                        <div><div>sLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi nobis veniam sed voluptates. Impedit quidem beatae consequuntur asperiores autem perferendis, deserunt in totam, quae modi minus? Magnam cum voluptatum, ut?</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2

                        <div>Quibusdam molestias, voluptate officiis numquam consequuntur tenetur sint facilis cupiditate ipsa totam animi atque dolorum, facere vel, deserunt mollitia minima doloremque at assumenda? Qui magni debitis pariatur obcaecati maxime enim.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does not work properly. To find out more, you can type more lines in the CONTENT section.
Also, by changing the selected tab, the contents of the previous tab (if its content is long) will still be displayed.

Comment: @hamidreza I just make a bit change, because your .tabs wrap are relative position, so you have to custom your height, but I change .tab max-height to conform content height

Comment: you can see my comment on css file.

Comment: I want the height of the content section to be flexible. But this code is still limited and has a fixed altitude. To understand this, you can repeat the entries in the following section several times.

<Div> Quibusdam molestias, voluptate officio ... </ div>

What should I do to be completely flexible height of the content.

I also thank you for the help

Comment: In addition, the number of text lines written in this section (CONTENT) is unclear and its height is completely unclear. Therefore, a variable value is required